# Setting Listview onItemClickListener to a specific Intent

Tags: android, list, listview, android-intent, onitemclicklistener

Hello I'm attempting to set up my onclicklistner to my list view so that I can open a range of intents for example I want the user to be able to press one of the options from the list and it makes a phone call or opens a website etc... Currently I have this set up working find when just linked to a simple button but now I wish to tidy up my display a little bit.

I have displayed the code below which shows my listview and hows its populated and I now just need to figure out how to add the intents. Can I get it to work depending on position or do I need to add a tag? Any examples would be most appreciated, I will continue to look and if I find a answer I will update my post.

```
public class ContactUs extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView contactUs;

String[] feature= {"Phone", "Email", "Website", "Opening Times"};
String[] click = {"click", "click", "click", "click", "click"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contact_us);



    contactUs = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contactUsListView);




    ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this,feature,click);
    contactUs.setAdapter(adapter);


    contactUs.setOnItemClickListener(new Itemlist());

}

class Itemlist implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


    }



    }
}
```

---

Small piece of code I currently use with a button called call, which I wish to transfer to the first item on my list view

```
call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }
            startActivity(callIntent);


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you won't change this array on runtime you can use switch case depenging on position. Something like this

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                break;
            }
            startActivity(callIntent);
            break;
        case 1:
            // Add the intent of choice
            break;
        case 2:
            // Add the intent of choice
            break;
        case 3:
            // Add the intent of choice
            break;
        case 4:
            // Add the intent of choice
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

switch (position) {
    case 0:
         //Add intent for Phone         
        break;
    case 1:
        //Add intent for Email
        break;
    case 2:
        //Add intent for Website   
        break;
    case 3:
        //Add intent for Opening Time
        break;

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers but I found a method and will update my question

Answer (score 0):

Its better to add tag to the view in getView inside ListViewAdapter because later if you change the positions in array.It doesnt effect

In ListViewAdapter,in getView() method add tag there and retrieve in the Activity so that you can use it by view.getTag() and use in switch case and do as @Max Zavernutiy said

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        if (contactUs.getAdapter().getItem(position).equals("Phone")){



            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }

            startActivity(callIntent);

        }
```